# WP return value from another function in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following JS script:

```
var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    sku: SKU
};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:myObject.url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Here I am calling a PHP function my_action.
In PHP I construct the function and the callback properly, and have these two functions:

```
function test_function()
{
    return "Test";
}

function my_action_callback() {
    $response = test_function();
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

This causes an error inside the alert: "Unexpected end of input".

However, should the callback look like this:

```
function my_action_callback() {
    $response = "Test";
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

I get "Test" returned in JS.

Why doesn't the first snippet work?

**Edit**

In fact, the error seems to stem from me calling the my_test_function in PHP.
The following PHP code also returns the unexpected end of input error:

```
function test_function()
{
    return "Test";
}

function my_action_callback() {
    $response = test_function();
    $response = "Test";
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any missing brackets.

Comment: Thanks Ervald!
I checked and there aren't any missing brackets. In fact, the AJAX call works when I do not try to get response from test_function, so this seems to be the problem...

Comment: Have you tried debugging the response? You could try to use a console.log instead of an alert, just to debug, or better yet, use firebug or chrome's inspector to access a real debugger.